# Attaching embedded xl sheet into Outlook in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to attach the embedded `xl` object  into outlook mail in vb.
my existing code is

```
Sheets("Doc Repository").Shapes.Range(Array("Object 1")).Select
Selection.Copy
```

Here "Doc Repository" is a sheet which has embedded .zip file.
with the above code, Object 1(zip folder) is getting copied to clipboard.

I am not sure how to paste the the copied zip file into outlook mail.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest saving the zip file to the disk and then add it as an attachment to the MailItem object using the [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553(v=office.15).aspx) mehtod of the Attachments class (see the corresponding property of the MailItem class).

```
Sub AddAttachment() 
   Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
   Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments 
   Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
   Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments 
   myAttachments.Add "D:\Test.zip", _ 
   olByValue, 1, "Test" 
   myItem.Display 
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Eugene, as part of automation process, some of the documents are embedded as object into an excel. Email has to be triggered with embedded documents as an attachement.

Comment: Did you try to save the embedded documents on the disk and then add them as attachments ?

Comment: Hi Eugene, i need to attach embedded object into outlook mail since the my spreadsheet will be shared with many others. So storing the doc in local drive and then attaching it outlook thru macro doesnot help.

Comment: There is no other way to attach an embedded object.